# Checking if two points are connected in boolean 2D list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Is there any quick way to find out, if two points on 2D boolean area are connected and you can mobe only up, down, left and right on a square with value True?
Let's say you would have following 6x6 2D list:

[image: 2D array]

In code, that would be:

```
bool2DList = [6][6]
bool2DList = { True,  True,  False, False, True,  True,
               False, True,  True,  False, True,  True,
               False, True,  True,  False, False, True,
               False, False, False, False, False, True,
               False, False, False, False, True,  True,
               False, True,  True,  True,  True,  True }
```

Green squares have value True and blue ones False. I was thinking about function( it would probably need to be recursive ), in which you would put a 2D list as a argument alongside with a list of tuples ( coordinates ) of several points and finaly one tuple of special point, it could have header like this:

```
def FindWay( bool2DList,listOfPoints,specialPointCoord )
```

In this example the special point would be the point P with coordinates 5;1. Let's imagine you would start walking from that special points. What points could you reach without stepping on the blue squares? In this example, only points P4 and P5 ( the output could be let's say the coordinates of those points, so 0;5 and 5;3 ). It would probably need to be recursive, but I have no idea, how the body should look like.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any code to show here. SO is not a code writing service. You will have to be much more explicit about your issue.

Comment: No I am not very sure how to start.

Comment: ...that's not a question.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid there is no trivial way to do this.  It's a graph traversal problem, and Python doesn't have built-in functions supporting that.  I expect that you'll want a simple implementation of a [breadth-first graph search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29).

Very briefly, you keep a list of nodes you've visited, but not handled; another list of nodes you've handled.  The steps look like this:

handled = []
   visited = [P]
   while visited is not empty:
       remove a node A from the visited list
       for each node B you can reach directly from A:
            if B is new (not in visited or handled list):
                put B on the visited list
       put A on the handled list

This will find all nodes you can reach.  If you're worried about a particular node, then inside the loop, check to see whether **B** is your target node.  When you put **B** on the visited list, put it on the front for depth-first, on the back for breadth-first.

In this application, "all the nodes you can reach" consists of the bordering ones with the same Boolean label.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option how you can code it:

```
A = np.array([[0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]]).astype(bool)
print A

[[False  True  True False]
 [ True False  True  True]
 [ True False  True False]
 [False  True False False]]
```

We can upgrade standard dfs function for our needs:

```
def dfs_area(A, start):
    graph = {}
    res = np.zeros_like(A)
    for index, x in np.ndenumerate(A):
        graph[index] = x
    visited, stack = set(), [start]

    while stack:
        vertex = stack.pop()
        x, y = vertex[0], vertex[1]
        if vertex not in visited and graph[vertex] == True:
            visited.add(vertex)
            if x < A.shape[0]-1:
                stack.append((x+1, y))
            if x > 1:
                stack.append((x-1, y))
            if y < A.shape[1]-1:
                stack.append((x, y+1))
            if y > 1:
                stack.append((x, y-1))
    res[tuple(np.array(list(visited)).T)] = 1

    return res
```

Assume that we want points connected to (1, 2) - second row, third value:

```
mask = dfs_area(A, (1,2))

>> mask

array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```